# How to run Wso2 Carbon management console on HTTP in older versions of Carbon?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I would like to run **Wso2 IS 4.1.0** on **HTTP**. Is there a way to achieve this? The property `<EnableHTTPAdminConsole>true</EnableHTTPAdminConsole>` doesn't seem to be available in Carbon 4.2 and older versions. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know the answer. But this version is EOL now.

Answer (score 0):

The Management Console uses the default HTTP-NIO transport, which is configured in the catalina-server.xml file in the /repository/conf/tomcat directory. This transport must be properly configured in this file for the Management Console to be accessible. Please read for more information https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon410/Running+the+Product